# How to find parent node and remove child

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm pretty inexperienced with JavaScript, and after doing quite a bit of searching and reviewing other threads, I'm having a difficult time figuring out how I can dynamically remove a field from a web form in a way that's similar to my use case (or more likely, I just don't get!).

My understanding is that an element can't be removed from DOM without a reference to the parent node. However, I am not entirely sure what I should be referencing as the parent node in my code when using removeChild(). I suspect that it is something in my HTML; it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

`<div>` within the HTML `<body>`

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar" text-align="center">
            myFormFieldLabel <button onclick="myFunction()">add</button></p>
        </div>          
        <div class="main" text-align="center">
            <form name="myForm" action="/" method="POST">
                some text goes here.
        </br>
            <hr>
        </br>
            <div class="fields" id="rf1">
            <!--added form fields will appear here-->
            </div></p>
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript that creates the field dynamically:

```
function myFunction(){
    var r = document.createElement('span');
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT")
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    var g = document.createElement("IMG");
    y.setAttribute("type", "text");
    y.setAttribute("placeholder", "myFormField");
    g.setAttribute("src", "delete.png");
    g.setAttribute("onclick", //should remove entire form input field(span)//);
    increment();
    y.setAttribute("Name", "myField" + "~input_" + i);
    r.appendChild(y);
    r.appendChild(g);
    r.appendChild(p);
    document.getElementById("rf1").appendChild(r);
}
```

Typically the error I have been running into when adjusting code here and there is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null`

Comment: I really want to suggest to use JQuery for this... but then I have just realize now that I cannot even code using the native language. I now hate myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a node from your document, you should first give it an id from your JavaScript code. That will make it a lot easier to remove programmatically later.

For example:

```
var r = document.createElement("span");
r.id = "myID";
var y = document.createElement("INPUT")
var p = document.createElement('p');
var g = document.createElement("IMG");
...
// Later
var p = document.getElementById("myID");
p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this seems to remove the image element itself. I need to remove the entire `<span>` tag. When substituting the in the variable for `<span>`, the error `Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null` occurs.